# Which Memcached client library should I use for .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, scaling

I've noticed there are a few solutions to allow the use of memcached on C# / ASP.NET:

- memcacheddotnet
- enyim.com Memcached Client
- BeIT

Which one should I use?  It seems like the enyim port has more active development, but I wanted to see what you guys recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [BeIT](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/) and i am happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx). Its Microsofts new alternative, its not stable yet but looks promising.

Comment: I evaluated Velocity, but I am going to wait until it's stable to use it.