# Memcached .NET Clients Comparisons

Tags: .net, memcached

I'm looking for a .NET Memcached Client, I founded 3 clients libraries.

Anyone have pros and cons about theses clients ?

[MemcachedDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/)

[BeIT](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/)

[Enyim](http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with [Enyim](http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached).  It was used in the examples in the [Using memcached](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/memcd/using-memcached) eBook, which is well worth the $9.  I found it to be fairly simple API to use.

I wouldn't go with MemcachedDotNet as it seemed to be lacking documentation and the most inactive of the 3 choices.

BeIT might be an alright choice based on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694928/which-net-memcached-client-do-you-use-enyimmemcached-vs-beitmemcached), however I haven't tried it yet myself.